# is it possible to make more than one HTTP request at the exact same time in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, fetch

I would like to send two or more HTTP requests in the exact same micro time, I know it's not possible maybe because Nodejs a single threaded language and has a queue.

I've created event emitter and added like 5 listeners, once I emit something 
it sends the HTTP requests.

```
const events = require('events');
const eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

const callback = ()=>{
    console.log(new Date().getTime());
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
};
eventEmitter.on('message',callback);

// second request
eventEmitter.on('message',callback);

// third request
eventEmitter.on('message',callback);

// forth request
eventEmitter.on('message',callback);

// fifth request
eventEmitter.on('message',callback);

eventEmitter.emit('message');
```

Here's the output

```
1559556527258
1559556527276
1559556527277
1559556527278
1559556527280
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
{ userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false }
```

I expected the requests to run in the exact same time. is there's any other way to send these requests in the exact same time?

Comment: May be you could explain what exactly you try to achieve. Requests to the same host are going to be serialised by your OS networks stack and NIC driver anyway.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I'm just trying to test out "MySQL" transactions if they're properly works, some users send simultaneously requests to my app, so they use the same e.g. coupon code twice.

Comment: Due to how TCP/IP work there is no such thing as receiving requests simultaneously - there has to be a packet that arrives first and another that arrives second. What tends to happen with languages with multithreading/multiprocessing like PHP and Java is that the **sequential** requests accidentally gets processed in parallel (simultaneously) because the second request creates a thread/process before the first request completes.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just trying to test out "MySQL" transactions if they properly work, some users send simultaneously requests to my app, so they use the same e.g. coupon code twice.

May be a simpler first step would be to write a small unit test that tests you business logic transactions without exercising the HTTP messaging part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, regardless the http requests, how to test some function twice at the same time?